# text not appearing in android.R.layout.simple_list_2 type of ArrayAdapter in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm using this simple code to populate custom row containing two text views. The rows are apparently getting populated(since the Toast shows that the hashmap is holding the two string values) but the rows in the list are appearing blank. This is strange. What can be the reason?

```
public class TwoHeaded extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<Map<String, String>> doubleDamage = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    doubleDamage = buildData();
    String[] from = {"platform","os"};
    int[] to = {R.id.tvTwoPlatform, R.id.tvTwoOs};
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, doubleDamage,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData(){
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    list.add(putData("Android", "Jelly Bean"));
    list.add(putData("Microsoft", "Windows"));
    list.add(putData("Apple","Macintosh"));
    return list;
}

private HashMap<String, String> putData(String platform, String os){
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put(platform, os);
    return item;
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, doubleDamage.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Here is the layout file that contains the two text views:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTwoPlatform"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTwoPlatform"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
    android:text="text For Platform "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTwoOs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    android:text="text For Os"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use your own layout that you posted instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` when you create the `SimpleAdapter`.

Comment: @luksprog tried that but still the rows are blank.

Comment: Is that the complete layout?

Comment: yes. it is the complete and only layout

Comment: @Luksprog it worked as per the comment below. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

see SimpleAdapter(context, data, resource, from, to) docs.

it reads:

- data A List of Maps. Each entry in the List corresponds to one row
  in the list. The Maps contain the data for each row, and should
  include all the entries specified in "from"
- resource Resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"

so each entry in the list should have fields "platform" and "os", like this:

```
private HashMap<String, String> putData(String platform, String os){
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("platform", platform);
    item.put("os", os);
    return item;
}
```

also, if you are using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 as a resource, your "to""

```
int[] to = {R.id.tvTwoPlatform, R.id.tvTwoOs};
```

should have texts ids defined in layout.simple_list_item_2.xml file:

```
int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
```

Comment: thanks mate, that helped !! Also I'd like to mention that instead of 'SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, doubleDamage,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);' in the code above, i must use 'SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, doubleDamage,
            R.layout.twoheaded, from, to);' to make it work

Comment: you can still use android.R.layout.simple_
list_item_2 but you have to change "int[] to" as I wrote in my answer